# How to change variable color in Emacs/ESS syntax highlighting?

Tags: emacs, ess

I am using Emacs 24.3 and ESS 13.05 with the theme [tangotango.el](https://github.com/juba/color-theme-tangotango). While the theme is restful on the eyes, variable names in R don't appear to be highlighted. In `tangotango-theme.el` I can find the following line:

```lisp
 `(font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground "tomato"))))
```

but this doesn't appear to have any effect. For example, in the screenshot below I would expect the variable `orl` to be highlighted in some shade of red. Instead it is the standard text colour for this theme.

[image: tangotango theme]

If I delve into ESS there is a file named `ess-font-lock.el` which contains a few references to the variable name face, like this one:

```
  (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-variable-name-face "Black"))
```

So it looks as if `font-lock-variable-name-face` has competing definitions. I don't understand the interaction between Emacs themes and these ESS definitions. Is ESS overriding the tangotango theme and if so, will changing the above line in `ess-font-lock.el` restore variable name highlighting? Or should I be looking somewhere else entirely?

Edit: note that `Cperl` mode does seem to respect the font lock:

[image: perl]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking in a wrong place. ess-font-lock defines themes. Some 10 years ago that was useful. Now there are generic themes like your tango-tango and ESS doesn't interfere with them.

The issue is that ESS does not define a font lock keyword that you are looking for. The reason is that <- is an assignment operator, and there is no an explisit variable definition statement in R. ESS only treats function definitions. That is, assignment of a function will be highlighted:

```
foo <- function(){}
```

Believe me or not, but you really don't want to highlight all your assignments. You can try it though with:

```lisp
(defvar ess-R-fl-keyword:assign-vars
  (cons "\\(\\(?2:\\s\"\\).+\\2\\|\\sw+\\)\\s-*\\(<-\\)"
        '(1 font-lock-variable-name-face)))

(add-to-list 'ess-R-font-lock-keywords '(ess-R-fl-keyword:assign-vars . t) t)
```

ESS implements a flexible font lock customisation mechanism on top of emacs font-lock system. See ESS>font-lock submenu.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of this menu. I have successfully added the new item - nice extensibility - and am using it to see how it goes. Appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sounds like it. If you see the problem only in that mode, and that mode explicitly changes the face, then that sounds like the culprit.  You should not need to change the source code, however.  Just do something like this (untested):

```lisp
 (add-hook 'ess-mode (lambda () (set-face-foreground "tomato")))
```

(I assume that's the right mode name; if not, correct it.)

But this is an ugly workaround -- you should not need to do that.  Consider filing a bug against the `ess-mode.el` code.  It should not trample on user settings such as faces that way.  If it wants to change the appearance by default then it should give users a *new* face that they can *customize*, instead of simply screwing with an existing face in a hard-coded way.

Comment: Thanks for this. I put that `add-hook` at the end of my ESS init file verbatim but it doesn't appear to have had an effect. I also tried `(add-hook 'ess-mode (lambda () (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-variable-name-face "tomato")))` but that didn't appear to work either. Based on your comment above ("if you see the problem only in that mode") I checked `CPerl` mode and the highlighting works okay there. Maybe @VitoshKa will appear and clarify at some point.

Comment: @SlowLearner: Yes, I forgot the face-variable argument for `set-face-foreground`.

Comment: @SlowLearner: Check that the mode is in fact called `ess-mode`. Put a call `(debug)` at the beginning of the `lambda`, to see what happens with the face foreground change. But I can guess that the problem is that it is the mode itself that overwrites the face foreground, *after* your hook function sets it to what you want.  If so then you have little choice but to redefine (or perhaps advise) the mode function (e.g., `ess-mode`). Unless there the mode defines another hook that you can use after it changes the face.

Comment: Looking at the ESS code (file `ess-font-lock.el`), it seems that it has its own "themes".  See the functions `(defun ess-font-lock-*`, each of which changes `font-lock-variable-name-face` and other faces.  You might need to redefine each of those functions. But take a look at the code to see if it doesn't provide a way for users to customize the behavior. It would hard to believe that such face changes would be hard-coded, without some alternative for users.

Comment: @SlowLearner: I don't have time to check the code in detail -- you can take a look. But perhaps you can just turn off `ess-font-lock-mode`.  Its doc says: "*Non-nil means we use font lock support for ESS buffers.
Default is t, to use font lock support.
If you change the value of this variable, restart Emacs for it to take effect."

Comment: Appreciate you looking into this. I haven't managed to get it to work using `(setq ess-font-lock-mode 0)` but I will continue to experiment and report back if I have any success.

Comment: Try customizing option `ess-font-lock-mode`, to turn it off.  You will need to restart Emacs, apparently.  You might also try customizing `inferior-ess-font-lock-input`.

Comment: You are looking in a wrong place. ess-font-lock-mode is not used anywhere and does not affect your fontification.

Comment: @VitoshKa: OK, sorry about the false route. I only grepped the source code and took a cursory look at what might be involved.